# How to make long URLs to go to a newline?

Tags: html

In my application I have some URLs that are very long strings (> 100 chars) and when are displayed break the template (eg: an "embedded" HTML `<div>` column is enlarged quite a bit). So, *how can I "simply" make possible those long URLs to go to a newline *without* to much effort and "complicate" the code?*

Comment: In what? PHP? ASP? ASP.NET? JSP? A candle, a picture of a webserver and an incantation in Latin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is that only css problem ? Try to add this to your css word-wrap:break-word;

Comment: And about *compatibility*... which browsers are compatible with the `word-wrap:break-word;` property?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/word-wrap#Browser_compatibility. I cannot be more precise :)